Django GET request a page with a button
I have a django view with html template with a form and a few buttons. When one of the buttons is pressed it sends a get request with a query param and depending on this param I render the page again but with different json paramethers. However I can't return the webpage with a second return.
This is the important code of the view for the question. I also tried this without return, but it doesn't work either. I tried using JsonResponce, but no success:
def card(request):
    cur_rk = 0
   
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.GET.get('C', '') == '-1':
            q1 = "SELECT MAX(RK) AS L_RK FROM B_DATA;"
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(q1)
                val = cursor.fetchall()
                cur_rk = val[0][0]
                
            return render(request, "card.html", get_db_data(cur_rk))
            
            
    return render(request, "card.html", get_db_data(cur_rk))

Here is the html code if it might help you:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create new card</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "enter_data">
        <form action = "" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class = "base">
                <h2>Базови данни</h2>
                <input type="number" class="field" placeholder="Enter RK" value = {{RK}} name="RK">
                <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Enter RN" value = {{RN}} name="RN">
                <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Enter Marka" value = {{Marka}} name="Marka">
                <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Enter Model" value = {{Model}} name="Model">
                <input type="number" class="field" placeholder="Enter G_PR" value = {{G_PR}} name="G_PR">
                <input type="number" class="field" placeholder="Enter KM" value = {{KM}} name="KM">
                <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Enter Kupe" value = {{Kupe}} name="Kupe">
                <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Enter Rama" value = {{Rama}} name="Rama">
                <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Enter Dvigatel" value = {{Dvigatel}} name="Dvigatel">
                <textarea class="field" placeholder="Enter Descr" name="Descr">{{Descr}}</textarea>
                <textarea class="field" placeholder="Enter Problem" name="Problem">{{Problem}}</textarea>
                <input type="date" class="field" placeholder="Enter R_DATA" value = {{R_DATA}} name="R_DATA">
            </div>
            <div class = "client">
                <h2>Данни за клиента</h2>
                <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Enter ime" value = {{ime}} name="ime">
                <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Enter telefon" value = {{telefon}} name="telefon">
            </div>
            <button type = "submit" class = "btn">Add card</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class = "control_btns">
        <button id="first" onclick="getData(0)">&lt;&lt;</button>
        <button id="previous" onclick="getData({{RK}}-1)">&lt;</button>
        <button id="next" onclick="getData({{RK}}+1)">&gt;</button>
        <button id="last" onclick="getData(-1)">&gt;&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        function getData(card) {
            let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/card/?C=' + card.toString();
            fetch(url);
        }
        function greet() {
            console.log('Hey there clicker!');
        }
    </script> 
</body>
</html>


To manage multiple return statements, ensure the view logic is well-structured. It seems you want to render the page differently based on the query parameter C. In this case, I suggest using a single render statement, as the context appears similar.
def get_db_data(rk):
    # This should return a dictionary of data to be passed to the template
    return {
        'cur_rk': rk,
        # ...
    }

def card(request):
    cur_rk = 0

    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.GET.get('C', '') == '-1':
            q1 = "SELECT MAX(RK) AS L_RK FROM B_DATA;"
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(q1)
                val = cursor.fetchall()
                cur_rk = val[0][0]

    context = get_db_data(cur_rk)
    return render(request, "card.html", context)


Thanks mate for the suggestion. I will have a look to the concept of context. Edit: This current suggestion didn't work, but I will do more research
